# Select Query Count LINQ C# Unity Not Working Correctly

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine

Could someone tell me why this query return a wrong value ?

First I generate 30 data at Player.estateagent. The Date must until 28/05.

```
System.DateTime Now = System.DateTime.Now;
System.DateTime thedate;
thedate = Now;
System.DateTime today = System.DateTime.Now;

for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
            Player.estateagent.Add (new classBundle (thedate, false));
            thedate = thedate.AddDays (1);

            Debug.Log ("DATE : " + Player.estateagent [i - 1].Date);
        }

int count = Player.estateagent.Where (j => {
                        return j.Complete == false && today.Date <= j.Date.Date;
                    }).Select (j=> j.Date.Date).Count ();

Debug.Log(count); // Here return 30, It must be 1
```

When i count i got 30 not 1. It should return 1 because i have query
 **`where j.complete == false && today.Date <= j.Date.Date`**

Can someone explain what mistake that i done ?

Thanks

Comment: It's working correctly. All the dates you add are greater or equal then today.

Comment: That's why, I dont' understand with mine. It always return 30. I must check my code again is there is something wrong.

Comment: Are you sure the variable count return 1 ? Mine return 30. I am not sure in here

Comment: No, 30 **IS** the correct value. estateagent contains only values with dates greater or equal than today.

Comment: The Value is like example : today (29/04/2017) ; estateagent Contain (29/04/2017,30/04/2017,01/05/2017 ......... until 28/05/2017) When i check today.Date <= j.Date.Date it is mean (29/04/2017 is lower or equal (29/04/2017,30/04/2017,01/05/2017 ......... until 28/05/2017)) . The result which equal must only 29/04/2017. the other is greater thatn 29/04/2017. Is it like that ? What have i misunderstood in here ?

Comment: If you want to get only item with current date, then change your condition to `where j.complete == false && today.Date == j.Date.Date`

Comment: i want to get the value example : today 29/04/2017 compare to 28/04/207, 29/04/2017,30/04/2017. I want to get below and equal to 29/04/2017. So i get 28/04/2017, 29/04/2017. How to get it ?

Comment: It's Look Like i misunderstood the LOGIC So far.. I just realize i just need to put today.Date >= j.Date.Date. Thank You Very Much

Answer (score 0):

Yes, So far I have asked a wrong question. This is just misunderstood about the logic.

The code i am provide above is running without an error. And the logic is right too.

The result is right with 30.

But i want to have a result which Equal and Greater ( <= ) than the Player.estateagent => Date Compire to today date.

So i just need to do today.Date >= j.Date.Date.

Just like that.